# PIP/Python packages installations going to the wrong PATH

Tags: python, ubuntu, directory, path

I use Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. I installed Python 3.9.5 normally, and some older versions of python in virtual environments.

When i change to the virtual environments (i.e: source pymodules/bin/activate) i can install packages without a problem.

But when i try to update pip/install packages in the "standard" 3.9.5 python i get this not on PATH message. (print)

For some reason, my vscode gives me two 3.9.5 python interpreters to code, even though i only did one installation... and if i try to install some package for python (like pandas), it doesn't work in neither of the 3.9.5 interpreters. (print)

I think i messed up in some basic PATH installation, how can i fix this? Do i need to send more information? Thanks.

print:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Due to a PATH issue. I'm pretty sure the problem occurred while installing Python. I recommend uninstalling Python and reinstalling it correctly.

As the Warning Said (don't recommend) You can simply do the command

`--no-warn-script-location`